# Kubuntu - Roccat keyboard does not work under GRUB and works partially in BIOS

Tags: grub2, keyboard, kubuntu, bios

**The system specification**

GRUB boot loader
OS: Windows 7 / Kubuntu 12.04 LTS
Keyboard: Roccat Isku
Motherboard: MSI Z77 MPower with the latest BIOS
SSD/HDD: Kingston HyperX 3K (AHCI in BIOS enabled), 2 other HDDs

I will provide more specific configuration if needed.

**The problem**

As stated in the topic I cannot navigate in the GRUB menu using mentioned keyboard (there is no problem when I use Logitech K360). I have tried both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports.

I cannot enter BIOS menu as well, however if I enter it using other keyboard, Roccat seems to work and I can navigate in the BIOS menu without any issues.

Any ideas how can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, but I have already solved the problem (after contacting ROCCAT and MSI): it was a Z77 chipset problem.

Some manufacturers already solved the problem - f.x. ASRock.
MSI has developed a beta BIOS release.
BIOS beta, flashing instructions and whole discussion is available here: 
http://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=162249.0

Works perfect allowing you to enter the BIOS, navigate in the BIOS and navigate in the GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause:

If the other keyboard you can access the BIOS with is a PS2 board: BIOS itself cannot handle USB input devices. You have to have USB legacy support activated. This option translates USB input to PS2 which the BIOS can handle. You have this option activated or else the Isku would not at all work in BIOS. But: If you wan't to access BIOS with an USB keyboard you have to wait until BIOS has activated USB Ports and with it the legacy support in the boot process. Only from this moment on BIOS will recognice your keypresses!

Another cause:

Maybe you have set the key with which you try to enter BIOS to another setting?